# Função substituta para a função .error() do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso saber que função usar no lugar da função `.error()`.

```
$('img').error(function() {
    $('img').attr('src','img/erro.gif');
});
```

O jquery 3.2.1 não possui essa função.
Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://api.jquery.com/error/):

> A partir do jQuery 1.8, o método `.error()` está depreciado. Use `.on(
>   "error", tratador)` para anexar tratadores de evento ao evento de erro.

Ou seja, mude seu código para:

```
$('img').on("error", function() {
    $('img').attr('src','img/erro.gif');
});
```

Comment: eu tentei essa função, mas não aparece a imagem que eu coloquei de erro

Comment: Certo, mas aí seu problema passa a ser outro. Crie uma nova pergunta descrevendo o novo problema, seu código atual e mais detalhes do seu problema (mensagens de erro, comportamento do depurador, código em mais detalhes etc.)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Então a imagem não existe ou o caminho dela está errado.

Comment: Refiz a pergunta, mas agora esta detalhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251097/n%C3%A3o-estou-conseguindo-carregar-a-imagem-que-demonstrar-erro-usando-jquery