# Não estou conseguindo carregar a imagem que demonstra erro usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

O exercício de hoje era carregar uma imagem quando der erro na outra imagem. Primeiramente eu tentei usar a função `.erro()`, mas descobri que ela foi descontinuada na versão 3.0. Depois eu testei a função `.on()`, mas da mesma forma não carregou a imagem. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Ps: sou iniciante em Jquery.

o código que eu fiz:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Evento navegador</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $('img').on('error', function(){
                $('img').attr('src', 'img/erro.jpg');
            });
        });

    </script>
    <img src="img/img_nao_existe.jpg" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

Obs: estou usando a última versão do Chrome e a versão 3.2.1 do jQuery.

Comment: Veja no console (F12) se retorna algum erro.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: então uma das duas imagens não existe, ou as duas. Verifique se o caminho está correto.

Comment: Como vc está querendo testar o `$('img').attr('src', 'img/erro.jpg');`, essa imagem `'img/erro.jpg` é a que não existe.

Comment: img_nao_existe.jpg 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

a img/erro.jpg existe *

Comment: Sim. Como a imagem na tag `<img>` não existe, deveria ser carregada a imagem no script. É essa imagem que você deve verificar se existe: `img/erro.jpg`

Comment: Porque seu código não tem nenhum problema.

Comment: eu sei que o caminho esta certo pq quando eu executo sem o ".on()"
ai sim ela aparece

Comment: Então tente usando este jQuery: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Funcionou com o CDN \o/ ........
Mas olha por algum motivo se eu uso o script offline não funciona .-.

Comment: Deveria funcionar offline. Faz um teste: salva o jQuery que mandei e faz um teste offline.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inclua o caminho da imagem na mesma declaração para capturar o evento de erro

```
$('img').on('error', function(){
   $(this).attr('src', 'img/erro.jpg');
}).attr('src','img/img_nao_existe.jpg');
```